# How to install tfs 2018 on windows 8

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, windows-8

I'm trying to install Microsoft tfs on my os (windows 8 enterprise), When I run setup, I encounter with this error:

```
Setup cannot continue because a dependent 
update needs to be installed before you can install 
this product on Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 R2,
 Windows 8 or Windows Server 2012.
```

So I started to search about the issue in the net but I couldn't find anything for windows 8, All I get was upgrading my windows to win server 2012 or 7 or 10... I was wondering if someone can help me here to get solution for installing tfs on windows 8.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 8 does not appear to be a [supported OS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/tfs/server/requirements) for TFS 2018. I would not recommend installing TFS on a client OS. Either install it on a real server or use [Azure DevOps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/?nav=min).